# MySQL/phpMyAdmin Query Row Count (1 row) vs mysql_num_rows' Count (0 row count)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's the code in question:

```
<?php // If search option is selected
 include 'db_connect.php';

 database_connect();
 $limit = 5;  // No of result per page
 $criteria = 1; // Search criteria
 $allResults=array();  // Array of results
 $searchOption = $_REQUEST['searchoption'];
 $searchField = $_REQUEST['searchfield'];
 $searchField = str_replace('+',' ', $searchField) ;
 $dbcolumn = "user_id";
 $dbtable = "profiles";
 $order = "user_id";

 if ($searchField){
    if ($searchOption == "People"){
    $words = explode(' ', trim($searchField));
    $searchField = $words[0];
    $dbcolumn = "profile_display_name";
    $dbtable = "profiles P, user_roles U, roles R";
    $order = "profile_first_name";
    $criteria =     " P.user_id = U.user_id AND U.role_id = R.role_id 
                    AND(`profile_display_name` LIKE '%$searchField%'   
                    OR `profile_first_name` LIKE '%$searchField%'   
                    OR `profile_last_name` LIKE '%$searchField%' 
                    OR `profile_email` LIKE '%$searchField%' 
                    OR `profile_state` LIKE '%$searchField%' 
                    OR `profile_zip_code` LIKE '%$searchField%'
                    OR `business_summary` LIKE '%$searchField%')";
    }
    //focus here folks (my comment to readers, not actual part of code
    else if ($searchOption == "Jobs"){
    $dbcolumn = "job_title";
    $dbtable = "job_postings";
    $order = "`created_date` DESC";
    $criteria = "(`job_title` LIKE '%$searchField%'   
    OR `job_description` LIKE '%$searchField%'   
    OR `client_name` LIKE '%$searchField%' 
    OR `city` LIKE '%$searchField%' 
    OR `state_abbr` LIKE '%$searchField%' 
    OR `zipcode` LIKE '%$searchField%') 
    AND `job_status` = 'Open'";
    }
    else if($searchOption == "News"){
    $dbcolumn = "";
    $dbtable = "";
    $order = "";
    $criteria = "1";   
    }

  //Pagination  
 if($dbtable){
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbtable WHERE $criteria");
    $no_of_rec =  mysql_num_rows($rs);
    $page = ($_REQUEST['page'])? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;
    $no_of_pages = ceil($no_of_rec/$limit);
    $offset  = ($page - 1)*$limit;

    echo "pagination #rows: $no_of_rec ";
 } 
}

// If the user enters a value in the search
if ($searchField){ 
   $resultcount = 0;
   if($dbtable)   {
    //  Search query executes
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $dbtable WHERE $criteria ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY $order ";
    $query .= "LIMIT $offset, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
    $resultcount = mysql_numrows($result);  

    echo "query: $query ";
    echo "result: $result ";
    echo "result count: $resultcount ";     
 }

 if ($resultcount <= 0){
     $allResults[] = "No match found";
 }
 else{
// Get search results from database
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$allResults[]=$row;
  }

 }
}
    else{
     $allResults[] = "No value entered";
    }
  ?>
```

Here's what the echo statements show:
`` pagination #rows: 0 query: SELECT * FROM job_postings WHERE (`job_title` LIKE '%Help Wanted%' OR `job_description` LIKE '%Help Wanted%' OR `client_name` LIKE '%Help Wanted%' OR `city` LIKE '%Help Wanted%' OR `state_abbr` LIKE '%Help Wanted%' OR `zipcode` LIKE '%Help Wanted%') AND `job_status` = 'Open' ORDER BY `created_date` DESC LIMIT 0, 5 result: Resource id #36 result count: 0 ``

(I left the echo printouts as they were so you can see what I see and how I see it.)

When I run the query in MySQL and phpMyAdmin, I get the row I'm looking for.

Can someone explain why mysql_numrows() thinks there are 0 results?

I've checked PHP.net and I have Googled this as well.  No luck so far.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you check for mysql errors ?

Comment: MySQL wasn't reporting errors, or did you mean the mysql_error() call?  How would I go about doing so?  I'm still new to PHP.

Comment: +1 for echoing out your query and testing the query in MySQL directly, which are the two things that new questioners usually need to be coaxed into doing. The next step would be to follow tereško's advice and echo the result of mysql_error() to see if mysql is providing any errors when PHP submits the query. You could also try putting a simple, explicit query into your PHP script and see if that works as intended. The fact that mysql_query() returns a resource means that you are connecting to your database (I think), but you could still be connecting in some unusual way.

Comment: I think I discovered what the issue is guys (while working on a different problem with a similar result): we made added a column to a table jpc that had the same name as a column on table jp.  There are two queries that reference both tables and both queries check the column in question.  When I ran the query myself including that column (job_status), MySQL told me the column name was ambiguous.  I don't know if it will fix this problem, but I was having the same issue (a return of 0 when inquiring about the results of a query).

I'll give my next "update at 11."

Comment: That solution did not solve my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

there is a mistype in this line

```
 $resultcount = mysql_numrows($result);
```

you should call mysql_num_rows()

you can use this code alternatively

```
$isExist = mysql_query("Select count(id) from ..."); 
$r = mysql_fetch_array($isExist);
if($r['COUNT(id)'] > 0){
//item exists
}else{
//item doesnt exist
}
```

Comment: Ali_D: I agree I need to make the change, I disagree that's the issue as this line also returns 0: 
$no_of_rec =  mysql_num_rows($rs);
and it is using the correct syntax/format/"spelling."

Comment: I will try your code when I get a chance though.
(I wanted to edit my original comment, but I was outside of the 5 min. window.)